# How to add subtitles below video

Tags: video-editor, subtitles

I have a video for which I want to a add subtitle strip below the original video. Like adding this new strip to the video to avoid affect the video that already has harcoded subtitles.

Which tool can I use to do this?

If open source, better.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ffmpeg https://ffmpeg.org, aegisubs http://www.aegisub.org/ also, doing a **search** on https://videoproduction.stackexchange.com

Comment: @stib Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if could be a duplicate with the other post you mention. I want a separate new full width rectangular section below the original video as target to show the subtitles in order to maintain without any other text the original video area. I hope make sense.